# Finding Coordinates of a point on a line in Coordinate Grid.

Tags: analytic-geometry

[image]

[image]

To solve this question should I use Pythagoras rule like this?
Please, any other method to get the coordinates?

[image]

Comment: (1) Where did the $4$ and $2$ in your diagram come from? (2) Ignoring that whole approach, if the distance from $B$ to $C$ is $u$, what do you know about the distance from $B$ to $E$? You need to read the sentence about $E$ really carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Write the parametric equation of the line segment from $B$ to $C$:
$$(7(1-t)+9t,8(1-t)+4t)$$
The point corresponding to a fixed $t$ is $t$ of the way from $B$ to $C$. It follows that if $BC=\frac23BE$ then $BE=\frac32BC$, i.e. we substitute $t=1.5$ into the abobe equation and get $E=(10,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your picture is not correct. Point E should have been outside of  BC

Otherwise you are on right track

Answer (score 0):

First, you’ve gotten the order of the points incorrect. For $C$ to be $2/3$ of the way from $B$ to $E$ it must lie between those two points.

That aside, there’s no need to use the Pythagorean theorem for this. If the lengths of two segments of the same line are in a certain proportion, then the differences of their endpoint coordinates are in the same proportion. So, if $BC=\frac23BE$, then $x_C-x_B=\frac23(x_E-x_B)$ and $y_C-y_B=\frac23(y_E-y_B)$. Plug in the known coordinate values and solve for the two unknown coordinates.